# How can I make an apk with google sign in?

Tags: android, firebase, debugging, google-signin

I am using Firebase's Google-Sign In and it works when I use my application in Genymotion but when I create the signed apk to install it on other devices the Google Sign In does not work, it says it is error 10, however my **debug key** SHA1 is correct in firebase. How can I make my application work on other devices with the Google Sign In?
I am making my app in java - android studio

Comment: When creating a singed apk, your debug key won't work because it's used in a signed apk and not debug. You need to use your release key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the signed APK SHA1 in the firebase. You can get it by using the following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your keystore path> -alias <your alias>
```

After that, put the new **google-services.json** file in your app and make a release APK.

Comment: Glad to help. Mark this as accepted and Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the different google-services.json in the release mode to make it work. Firebase provides different google-services.json for debugging and release mode and we need to make sure we are using the right one when creating the build. Please go to your firebase console and create a release mode JSON file for signed APK.